# xls2csv: wrong date cells parsing

Tags: parsing, xls

I format dates with the command line option -f %Y-%m-%d  or even %d-%b-%y

but each date comes out four years and one day ahead of the date I input

for example, date `01.06.2012` after parsing without -f option comes as `2016-06-02`
toying with -f gives same result

What is the reason? Are there any workarounds,
except hardcode and substract back these 4 years and 1 day?

I am using xls2csv (by V.B.Wagner, comes with catdoc package in debian)
and switching to another parser can be very expensive option

Comment: Four years and one day sounds exactly like the difference between the Windows 1900 and the Mac 1904 Calendars. What calendar is set for the original workbook?

Answer (score 3):

Tools **xls2csv** is a Perl application that uses `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` library.

Based on such library [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm#KNOWN_PROBLEMS), one of **known problems** is:

- **If** Excel has date fields where the specified **format is equal to the system-default** for the short-date locale, **Excel does not store the format**, but defaults to an internal format which is system dependent. In these cases ParseExcel uses the date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

So you probably manipulate with Excel file that does not contain date formating due to above listed issue.

Answer (score 3):

That's a known bug.  A patch is available at
https://www.wagner.pp.ru/cgi-bin/cvstrac/catdoc/tktview?tn=14,4

It works.
By the way, there are two programs called xls2csv, we're talking about the one from the catdoc package, not the Perl program.